# passing command line parameters to spring boot services inside docker container

Tags: spring, docker, spring-boot

I have got a set of spring boot apps that I would like to package as docker containers.
I am using the following Dockerfile to create the container for one of the services:

```
FROM java:8
VOLUME /tmp
ADD myservice.jar app.jar
RUN bash -c 'touch /app.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Inside, the services access some environment properties like for instance:

```
@Value("${my.test.param:default}") 
String testParam;
.
.
.
logger.info("param value is = "+testParam);
```

Now, I would like to be able to override this setting via `docker run` command line like this

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e my.test.param=changed mygroup/myservice:0.0.1
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. I keep seeing the default value for the parameter `my.test.param`.
I searched for ways to automatically add all `-e` parameters at the end of the `ENTRYPOINT` line, but didn't find any. Is there some general solution for this?

Comment: did your try `docker run --entrypoint` see the doc https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/entrypoint-default-command-to-execute-at-runtime

Comment: I found out that by setting ` -e MY_TEST_PARAM=changed` (instead of the syntax `my.test.param` it works